# datepicker continuously popping out the box on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with jquery datepicker via IE8, when I clicked the input form
the calendar box pops = this is normal, but after choosing a date from the calendar box,
the box is still there, and it won't go away unless i click away on some other portion of
the screen. but on other browsers, i'ts not like that. any idea how to fix this ?
here's my code

```
//html
                    <div class="row">
                    <label>Date of Birth <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="datepickercv" name="dob" value="<?php echo $_POST['dob']; ?>" />
                    </div>


//js

$(function(){
  $('#datepickercv').datepicker({changeYear: true,changeMonth: true,yearRange:'1940:2011',defaultDate:+7});
})
```

Comment: I tested. It work fine http://jsfiddle.net/bUwNg/

Comment: have you tried it on IE ? , the pop up stays after selecting a date

Comment: Is it possible some other JavaScript has an IE error (ex. extra comma in object) that prevents execution at some point?

Comment: @sasori Can you check you IE left bottom corner ? Is there any Error sign ? If have please fix it first.

Comment: there's no error at all, I dunno what happened..thanks

Answer (score 0):

which version of jquery-ui are you using? Even I had the same issue on IE8. This seems to be a bug in 1.8.15, check [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7623), upgrading to 1.8.16 fixes the issue!